# Content scripts in future Chrome apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, browser-extension

I just read the news that [Google will not support packaged Chrome apps](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/08/google-is-killing-chrome-apps-on-windows-mac-and-linux/)

How will apps be able to function that are based on content scripts?
For example : adblockers, tampedmonkey, cookie editors etc etc

Comment: @DylanMeeus I think they are both the same. But at least they both use the Web app store that will stop working in the future

Comment: Well I'm sorry to post my question here but, is it "only" for the chrome apps or the projects make with NW.js, Electron, etc (aka cross-platform JS apps using chromium) will have problems too ? :s  
@Dylan Meeus, yeah you're right, it's not the right place and can disturb the main subject. Sorry. (Must I delete my comment ?)

Comment: @Aethyn best to post that as another question. I don't immediatly see the relation between Electron and Chrome apps either. Can you put an electron project on there? I'm not sure :-)

Comment: I think this announcement made lots of confusion. But I'm happy my extensions won't go away (just yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Chrome apps** and **Chrome extensions** are not the same. They are stopping the support of chrome apps, but not of chrome extensions.

From the blogpost on chromium we read:

> In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes. (http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html)

As you can see, extensions and themes will actually still be available, and at this moment google did not announce anything with regards to the discontinuation of chrome extensions. (And personally, I think that extensions are quite popular and I don't see a reason for them to stop supporting it, unlike the apps)